# Load Cucumber tests but don't execute them

Tags: ruby, cucumber, editor

I'm very new to Ruby, so, sorry if the answer is obvious.

#### Given

Existing project which consists exclusively of Cucumber tests (features). The project has a Gemfile, and `env.rb` under `features/support` which appends project directories to `$LOAD_PATH` and requires several libraries.  I can run these tests by executing

```
bundler exec cucumber -r features
```

#### Question

I want to be able to load the support files into a REPL (say, `pry`), for the purposes of code inspection.  In other words, I'd like to create a `console` -like script that loads up all the code that is used in the tests, but doesn't execute the tests.  I need this for the editor that uses this kind of REPL for things like code completion, navigation, refactoring etc.  Since this "application" doesn't have anything resembling an entry point, I'm at a loss as to how to create one.  My efforts to require all files in the `support` directory so far had been unsuccessful, in particular, due to the use of `World()` top-level method, which I believe is defined by Cucumber.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to accomplish but if you have say `pry` gem loaded in your Gemfile in test group, you should be able to just throw in a `binding.pry` command inside any test to inspect the code / environment.

Might look something like this:

## Gemfile

```
group :development, :test do
  gem "pry"
end
```

You could also use a rake task and load the environment taking the same approach.

## lib/rake/sometask.rake

```
namespace :load do
desc "inspect code"
  task :code, => :environment do
    binding.pry
  end
end
```

and run `bundle exec rake load:code` for example

Comment: No, no, what I want is to start the Rails-like console with the test code loaded, but not executed. I found a way to do that by calling `Cucumber::Runtime.new(...)` and then calling some initialization of this class. But I still need to validate that it actually did what I needed it to do.

Comment: ok well good luck and if you figure it out, post your answer as it's still unclear what you're actually trying to do.